# inserting distance AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA into Google Fit

Tags: android, google-fit

From my App I'm trying to insert distance data into Google-Fit:

```
insert(DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA, distanceMeters, fromMillis, toMillis);

public void insert(DataType type, float value, long fromMillis, long toMillis) {

  DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
    .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
    .setDataType(type)
    .setAppPackageName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
    .build();
  DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);

  DataPoint point = dataSet.createDataPoint();
  point.setTimeInterval(fromMillis, toMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  point.setFloatValues(value);
  dataSet.add(point);

  Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(client, dataSet).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Everything works smoothly - authorization granted, status.isSuccess() returns `true` - but the distance never shows up in the Google-Fit App.

If I'm inserting expended calories for the same interval, they are shown as expected:

```
insert(DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, kiloCalories, fromMillis, toMillis);
```

Any idea why AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly declaring setDataType inside your insert function:

```
setDataType(DataSource.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
```

I think this similar to the example mentioned in [Insert Data guide](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/history#insert_data):

```
// Create a data source
DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
.setAppPackageName(this)
.setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
.setStreamName(TAG + " - step count")
.setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
.build();

// Create a data set
int stepCountDelta = 950;
DataSet dataSet = DataSet.create(dataSource);
// For each data point, specify a start time, end time, and the data value -- in this case,
// the number of new steps.
DataPoint dataPoint = dataSet.createDataPoint()
.setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).setInt(stepCountDelta);
dataSet.add(dataPoint);
```

Comment: Actually I was already setting the dataType, but your example made me aware of a difference: I was setting the value with #setFloatValues() but using #getValue(Field).setFloat() is correct. Thanks.

Comment: can you resolve this problem ?

Please paste the code

Comment: @svenmeier did you resolve this issue?? even I am confused with the delay of data being inserted to google fit app. I inserted a heart rate value and it was successfully inserted but it was never displayed on the google-fit app.

Comment: @groot My users are regularily reporting huge delays until the data shows up. I really don't understand what's going wrong with Google Fit.